# Como esperar que una funcion termine para invocar otra que utilice lo que acabe de crear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

tengo una función llamada init() que se encarga de crear todos los elementos de una página con jQuery, entre otros esta parte:

```
$('.suggestions__content').append(
  `<li class="suggestions__item ${selecionado > 0 ? 'box-check' : ''}" idSKU="${id}">${this.buildContentItem(
    item
  )}</li>`
)
```

Lo que quiero hacer es poder seleccionar esos desde otra función cuando ya esa función haya terminado de crear todos los elementos para poder utilizarlos,

ej:

```
function otherFunction(){
       const elementosHtml = $('.suggestions__item')
       console.log(elementosHtml)
}
```

Cuando llame a la función me imprima en consola y pueda obtener sus atributos, si la llamo normalmente imprime el selector, pero no trae los elementos, no los encuentra porque presumo, no se han añadido al documento

Comment: No entiendo tu problema, a mi si mie funciona tu codigo. Obtengo una lista de los elementos creados por append

Answer (score 0):

Si el problema es que no e han renderizado (creado o cargado en el DOM), como tu dices, intenta usar `$(document).ready` para cerciorate de que todo el contenido ha sido cargado y creado.

```
function otherFunction(){
    // dentro de esta funcion debes de poder usar los selectores y obtener el array de objetos
    // const elementosHtml = $('.suggestions__item')
    // console.log(elementosHtml)
    alert();
}

// $(document).ready espera a que todo el DOM sea cargado y creado
$(document).ready( function(){
    otherFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo este ejemplo en el que primero se agregan elementos al `<ul>` y posteriormente se ejecuta tu segunda función.

Debes adaptar el ejemplo a tu código ya que no proporcionaste el contexto completo.

El snippet toma un par de segundos en ejecutarse.

```js
//Ejecutar la función init() al cargar la pagina
init();

//Declaración de la función init()
function init() {
  //Modifica esta parte con tu código
  $('.suggestions__content').append('<li class="suggestions__item">1</li>');
  $('.suggestions__content').append('<li class="suggestions__item">2</li>');
  $('.suggestions__content').append('<li class="suggestions__item">3</li>');
  //Ejecutar la función otherFunction() después de agregar los <li>
  otherFunction();
}

//Declaración de la función otherFunction()
function otherFunction() {
  const elementosHtml = $('.suggestions__item')
  console.log(elementosHtml)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="suggestions__content"></ul>
```

Otra opción que tienes disponible es usar `async` y `await`, pero te lo dejo de consulta, creo que en la comuindad hay varios ejemplos.